# Typo3 Backend HTML Element - Format value wrong

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

I have a problem: when I create a HTML-Element in the Backen of Typo3 (Version 9) and save it with some HTML-Content. All fine so far the output on the frontend works perfect. But when I want to edit, it seems like that the backend want to parse it wrong - I got the output as following: all tags are HTML-Entities now and the code is wrapped in some p-Tags (when I want to save now the code is saved this way to the db and frontend gets also wrong output for these element).

Does anybody have the same issue or an solution?

`<p>&lt;form action="/action_page.php"&gt;   <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>   &lt;input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="John"&gt;<br>   <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>   &lt;input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"&gt;<br><br>   &lt;input type="submit" value="Submit"&gt; &lt;/form&gt;</p>`

[image: Typo3 Backend HTML Element displays content wrong]

Answer (score 0):

The extension responsible for the code highlighting is `t3editor` (typo3/cms-t3editor). You can deactivate or remove it.

I cannot reproduce this problem in a v9.5.26.